# C# DataGridView - Editing the Entire Columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to make an alarm system via dataGridView. I have 2 columns named "Name, Time". Those in the Time Columns should decrease by 1 per second. What do I need to do to edit them all at once?

Comment: It's called a loop.

Comment: I'm going to do the time reduction via a loop, but I don't know how to get them all in the same loop.

Comment: You want to do something to every row in the grid. You loop through the rows and, in the loop, you do something to the current row. That's how loops work: one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0) and include it into the datagridview.
Otherwise you can iterate through the rows and update everytime the "Time" column value.
For both you have to run a timer. Tipp at this point: Let it run in different Threads: So you have one for the UI(-Interaction), one for other working parts and one for the timer, which calls every second the Updatefunction of the time column.

Comment: I need to do some work on using DataTable. For now, I got a workaround using the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the list by transferring the times less than 30 seconds to the listbox using the for loop. As a temporary solution it works fine for now.

```
  DateTime d1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
           // MessageBox.Show(d1.ToString());
            if (d1 < dateTimePicker1.Value) // If less than 30 seconds send to listbox
                listBox1.Items.Add(d1);
        }
        ListCheck();
```